# STL, iostream, new, delete in C/C++ for CUDA

Tags: c++, c, stl, cuda, iostream

Can I use STL,iostream,new, delete in C/C++ for CUDA?

Comment: You can only use STL, iostream, new and delete in **C++**

Comment: Closest related thing I could find was http://code.google.com/p/thrust/.

Comment: Did you read through [the CUDA documentation](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation)? Particularly the [Thrust Quick Start Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/CUDALibraries/doc/Thrust_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf)? What made you question this?

Comment: @ the people downvoting. Sure, this might be a question that has an obvious answer to most people but sometimes not all. He is asking a legitimate question and sure we have basic rules like "do a google search first", but if you took 2 seconds to look you'd see he is brand new to the site. How about giving a nice warm welcome and a reference to the FAQ or something instead of having his first impression of the site be a bunch of people driving by and downvoting him.

Comment: If you feel that you need to use things like STL and iostream in CUDA code then you *probably* don't understand the problem domains that GPGPU is useful for

Comment: as far as I know, nvopencc is a C compiler. It does support some C++ features, as templates for example, but you are very limited. So, no STL, exceptions, iostream, etc. 
I've heard that some people were able to compile .cpp files with g++/msvc compilers and then link the objects with nvcc, but I've never tried that.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a Fermi class GPU (so compute capability >=2.0), and are using CUDA 4.0 or later, then both `new` and `delete` are avialable for use in device code. STL containers and algorithms and iostream are not supported.

If you want to use "STL like" operations with CUDA, you might be interested in the [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) template library. It allows host code to transparently interact with the GPU using container types and implements a number of very useful data parallel primitives, like sorting, reduction, and scan. Note that this is still a host side apparatus, Thrust and its containers cannot be used inside your own kernel code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down some.

#### The general case: Can I use C++ standard library construct XYZ on the GPU?

No, you can't use standard library code on the GPU (i.e. in your device-side code). The most direct obstacle is that the standard library is not targeting the CUDA compiler - not indicating its code should be compiled both for host-side and device-side execution. But even if this technical issue was dispensed with someone, there are various reasons why quite a bit of the standard library would not work as-is, or at all, on the GPU.

#### STL

As talonmies [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986856/1593077), the Thrust library provides some STL-like functionality, in a useful and nicely packaged way. But it's still mostly a "no" as an answer to your question since:

1. Its interface is host-side rather than device-side. That is, it will do things for you using the GPU, but those will be under the hood; it's not a toolbox to write your own device-side code.
2. It covers a small part of the STL: As data structures go, it's essentially just vectors (AFAIK - I haven't scoured the code); streaming on-GPU data using iostreams or a similar abstraction is not supported

#### iostreams

No, you can't use iostream in CUDA device-side code. We do have C-style printf, however: `printf("my_int_value is %05d\n", my_int_value);`. This is a *very* different beast than the standard library `printf()`, though, since it needs to send data across the PCI bus and have the driver get it to the host-side process' output stream.

See the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/)'s [section on formatted output](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#formatted-output) for details.

#### `new` and `delete`

The `new` and `delete` operators do work, similarly to on-device `malloc()` and `free()` - which is different than on the host-side and somewhat limited; see RobertCrovella's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417436/1593077) on this matter and the links in it.

I would advise, however, that you think very carefully about whether you really need to do on-device memory allocation and de-allocation; it's likely to be costly performance-wise, and  often/usually you can do better by pre-allocating memory via a host-side API call.