# Which memory space does cudaMalloc allocate memory in?

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

If I understand correctly, CUDA devices have a few different [memory spaces](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#device-memory-spaces). (e.g. register, local, shared, global, etc). When calling `cudaMalloc()`, which memory space does allocated memory reside?

For example:

```
__global__ mykernel (void *p) {
    /* What memory space does p point to? */
    printf("p: %p\n", p);
}

int main() {
    void *p;
    assert(cudaMalloc (&p, 1024) == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    mykernel<<<1,1024>>> (p);
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356) does not mention at what level the memory is allocated. It only says

> Allocates `size` bytes of linear memory on the device and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The allocated memory is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. The memory is not cleared.

It seems the memory would have to reside in one of global/constant/texture spaces, but which one?

Is it also safe to assume the memory will never be in local/register/shared memory space?

Answer (score 3):

**global**

`cudaMalloc` allocates in global memory.
The other method for global memory allocation is using `new` and `delete` inside kernel.

```
__global__ void myKernel(int N)
{
     int* a = new int[N]; // not recommended
     delete [] a;
}
```

---

**shared**

For dynamic shared memory you use sth like

```
extern __shared__ int s[];
```

And launch kernel like

```
myKernel<<<1,n,n*sizeof(int)>>();
```

Or just `__shared__ int s[4];` (inside kernel) for static shared memory

---

**register**

And for register you can think of automatic allocation in C++(just from syntax point of view):

```
int example = 0;
int moreExample[4]
```

the main difference is if you run out of register memory you will have register spilling and the variable may end up in global memory instead of register.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the last part. Can I think of register memory as kind of a "stack" for each thread? And how are register and local memory related?

Comment: @user8675309 I meant just the syntax. They are like automatic variables. They die when they go out of scope....

Comment: Isnt new working on local? Every thread gets a different pointer.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik "new and delete operate on device heap memory. The device allows for a portion of the global (i.e. on-board) memory to be allocated in this fashion."https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417318/cuda-new-delete. yes every thread gets different pointer.

Comment: Another method for global memory allocation is the static method, using the `__device__` decorator.  (`cudaMalloc()` from host code would be considered dynamic allocation)  In addition to `new` and `delete` for in-kernel usage, equivalent in-kernel behavior is possible with `malloc()` and `free()`, and also `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaFree()`.