# Passing class object to __global__ kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I would like to pass a class object to a global kernel and execute its member functions in it. All my efforts up to now has been unsuccessful. Below I am giving a detailed description of what I am trying to do.

I have class PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU implemented like this:

```
class PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU: public PDE_Parabolic_GPU
 {
  public:
   __host__ __device__ PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU();
   __host__ __device__ ~PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU();
   __host__ __device__ Solve();
   __host__ __device__ Setup();
   ...

  //data
  gdd_real*   an;
  gdd_real*   bn;
  gdd_real*   cn;
}
```

where gdd_real is

```
struct gdd_real 
{
    double2 val;
        __host__  __device__ gdd_real(double hi, double lo) {val.x = hi; val.y = lo;}
    __host__  __device__ gdd_real(double h){val.x = h; val.y = 0.;}
    __host__  __device__ gdd_real(){};
};
```

In my main(), I am doing the usual cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy in order to pass my class object to the global kernel:

```
PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU pdes_host;
PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU *pdes_dev;
cudaError_t cudaStatus;
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&pdes_dev, 1 * sizeof(PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU));
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(pdes_dev, &pdes_host, sizeof(PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
pdegpu<<<1,1>>>(pdes_dev);
cudaStatus = cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(&pdes_host, pdes_dev, sizeof(PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaStatus = cudaThreadExit();
system("pause");
```

pdegpu kernel is as follows:

```
__global__ void pdegpu(PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU *pdes)
{
  pdes->Setup(); //initializes class members an, bn, cn using "new" 
  pdes->Solve();    
}
```

My first problem: the program crashes at pdes->Setup() during debugging;

The second problem is: if I change the kernel to use local object such as below, the program crashes after system("pause") statement in main() during debugging.

```
__global__ void pdegpu()
{
      PDE_Parabolic_Num_GPU pdes;  //using local object
      pdes.Setup(); 
      pdes.Solve(); 
}
```

These are two cases when the program crashes during debugging using Nsight. But when I run the program without debugging, the second version of pdegpu(which uses the local object) crashes at pdes.Solve(). 
Can anyone help me to resolve theese problems? 
Thank you,

Comment: You cannot use `new` in GPU code. You have to allocate it on the host via `cudaMalloc` and pass in the pointers.

Comment: @lethal-guitar... Who told you that? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8986856/1231073)!

Comment: @lethal-guitar: that hadn't been true for almost three years.

Comment: Ok... I'm pretty sure `malloc` is still not possible, so I just assumed this applies to `new/delete` as well..

Comment: Ok, turns out I was wrong about that as well.. Hmm, good to know..

Comment: I am not sure how safe it is to pass an object via copy, I would suggest that you try `new` and `delete` inside the kernel, after having defined the constructor classes as `__device__` code. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978720/1608616) is a good advice that I found useful.
You can store the result in some package of data and then copy only the result back to host.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing pointers to `gdd_real`? You could just place objects of this type directly in your class. This way, you will avoid memory-related problems.

So why not just use:

```
    //...
    gdd_real   an;
    gdd_real   bn;
    gdd_real   cn;
}
```

Comment: Because an, bn, cn are arrays of gdd_real. For example, I initialize it like an = new gdd_real[200] in the Setup function.